# What are the implications of having a model belong to both a child and its parent in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following relational setup in a Rails 4.2 application.  If I wanted Tail to belong_to Kite so I could reference a relationship between the general Kite class and its associated tails - is this a Rails anti-pattern?  At this point in the code I would need to add a kite_id to tail.  (It currently has both a beach_kite_id and a snow_kite_id).  Is there any way to make use of the aforementioned *_kite_id's without having to add a kite_id to tail?

```
class Kite

end

class BeachKite < Kite
  has_many :tails
end

class SnowKite < Kite
  has_many :tails
end

class Tail
  belongs_to :snow_kite
  belongs_to :beach_kite
end
```

Answer (score 0):

[STI (Single Table Inheritance)](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) and [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) allow you to simplify the associations like so:

```
class Kite < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tails, as: :kite
end

class BeachKite < Kite
end

class SnowKite < Kite
end

class Tail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :kite, polymorphic: true
end
```

The `tails` table stores both `kite_id` and `kite_type` as it is [polymorphic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Try it:

```
snow_kite = SnowKite.create(tails: [Tail.create])
Tail.last.kite => snow_kite

beach_kite = BeachKite.create(tails: [Tail.create])
Tail.last.kite => beach_kite
```